# Ubuntu 22.04 won't reboot

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 22.04, chroot

Upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 - everything worked fine. Then I tried activating `unattended-upgrades` and let it install a new kernel and reboot. Machine never recovered.

Grub has the following kernels to choose from:

[image: grub]

Booting into either recovery mode gives a kernel panic:

[image: panic]

Booting "normally" just hangs:

[image]

Booting a 22.04.1 live iso I can see and mount the disk:

[image: lsblk]

I can chroot into the non-booting install:

[image: chroot]

But the chroot is incredible broken - so re-installing grub is a no-go:

[image: invalid ELF]

Both loaded kernel and installed kernel are some version of 5.15:

[image: kernel five fifteen]

Why can't I run any binaries in the chroot?

If I bind mount binaries/libs from the live cd into the chroot it gets a bit more functional:

[image: more bind mounts]

[image: ip works]

[image: grub install seem to work]

But the boot gets no further:

[image: boot still no go]

How should I restore the machines ability to boot?

Comment: Ended up re-installing - but I'd sure like to get some ideas of how I could have saved the install.